# How to differentiate two different signals from their combined signal

Tags: matlab, audio-processing, beamforming, adaptive-algorithms

I am having two omnidirectional microphones connected in endfire configuration. I am playing a male speech from  0 degree (front direction) of the endfire microphone configuration  and female speech from 180 degree(behind the endfire microphone configuration) and the data grabbed by both the microphones were recorded. The data grabbed by both the  microphones have combined male and female speech data samples. How to separately differentiate the male speech alone from this combined data grabbed by the microphones

Answer (score 1):

If the recording is anechoic than this is simple enough: assuming that the distance between the microphones is $d$ than you can estimate the front source as

$$x_f(t) = m_f(t-d/c_0) - g \cdot m_r(t)$$

where $m_f(t)$ is the signal from the front microphone, $m_r(t)$ the signal from the rear microphone, $c_0$ the speed of sound and $g$ a gain factor that depends on the exact geometry but close to 1 if the distance to the speaker is significantly larger than the distance between the microphones.

This will mostly eliminate the rear source but also add some significant spectral combing to the front source, so depending on your application, you may want to apply equalization to pretty it up a bit.

If this is reverberant recording, this is a very, very hard problem to solve.